# Problema con JOptionPane probando un try catch

Tags: java

Mi `JOptionPane` se repite cuando ingreso un valor que no es un número para probar my `try catch`.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class anyoBisiesto {


    private static int anyo;

    public void ingreseAnyo (){
        String anyoIngresado = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el a\u00f1o");
        try{
            anyo = Integer.parseInt (anyoIngresado);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,  "El valor ingresado no es un n\u00famero", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        }



    public boolean esBisiesto (int anyo){
        boolean esBisiesto = true;
            if (anyo % 4 == 0){
                if (anyo % 400 ==0)
                    esBisiesto = true;
            }
            else if (anyo % 100 != 0){
                esBisiesto = false;
            }
            else {
                esBisiesto = true;
            }
            return esBisiesto;
        }




        public static void main(String[] args) {


        anyoBisiesto anyo1 = new anyoBisiesto();
        anyo1.ingreseAnyo();

        if (anyo1.esBisiesto (anyo) == true){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "El a\u00f1o es bisiesto");
        } else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "El a\u00f1o no es bisiesto");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. ¿Qué mensaje se repite? Nada en el código me hace pensar que haya ningún bucle ni similar; ¿seguro que no estás confundiendo un mensaje con otro?

Comment: Cuando ingreso un caracter que no es un numero para probar mi try y catch, me tira el mensaje de error (o sea, que funciona bien el try y catch) pero justo despues me tira el JOptionPane que me dice que el ano es bisiesto

Comment: En "esBisiesto ()" , el dentro del primer if tienes otro "if (anyo % 400 ==0)", el resultado final será true sin importar esa condición

Answer (score 0):

```
public Integer ingreseAnyo (){
    String anyoIngresado = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el a\u00f1o");
    try{
        //si el año es numérico lo retornas
        return Integer.parseInt (anyoIngresado);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,  "El valor ingresado no es un n\u00famero", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    //si hubo error en el número retornas nulo y ya sabes que ya mandaste
    //el mensaje de error
    return null;
}
```

En main, si hubo error numérico ya no mandas otro mensaje porque ya enviaste el mensaje de error de año no numérico, y si no hubo error entonces valida que sea bisiesto.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {


    anyoBisiesto anyo1 = new anyoBisiesto();
    Integer anyo = anyo1.ingreseAnyo();
    if (anyo == null) {
       //hubo error en año ingresado, salimos xque ya enviamos error
       return;
    }
    if (anyo1.esBisiesto (anyo){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "El a\u00f1o es bisiesto");
    } else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "El a\u00f1o no es bisiesto");
    }
}
```

Comment: A la hora de poner los null (especificamente en int ingreseAnyo, me da error y dice que null no se puede convertir a int

Comment: public Integer ingreseAnyo() // lo tienes como Integer o como int?

Comment: Lo tenia como int, en vez de Integer. Ya funcionó. Me podrías explicar la diferencia? y gracias de antemano

Comment: int es un tipo primitivo, contiene un valor. Por ejemplo int valor = 8; la variable valor contiene el valor 8. Y no puede valer nulo.  La clase Integer encapsula un Int primitivo, por ejemplo Integer valor = new Integer(8). En este caso valor puede ser nulo. La clase Integer te sirve cuando el valor puede ser nulo o cuando quieres usar alguno de los métodos de dicha clase. Te recomiendo busques la clase java.lang.Integer

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
        anyo = Integer.parseInt (anyoIngresado);
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,  "El valor ingresado no es un n\u00famero", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
--> Continuar
```

Así es como funcionan las excepciones en Java. Tu código:

1. Intenta convertir `anyoIngresado` a `int`.
2. Si va bien, asigna el valor a `anyo` y pasa a "Continuar"
3. Si no va bien, lanza una excepción y pasa al `catch`

   1. el `catch` muestra el mensaje y pasa a "Continuar".

En los dos casos (excepción o no), se sale del método normalmente y continúa la ejecución del programa. Pero si ha habido excepción, no has asignado un valor a `anyo` y mantiene el valor por defecto (0) que es el usará para hacer todos los cálculos.

Si quieres que en caso de excepción se altere el funcionamiento, tienes varias opciones:

- En el `catch`, lanzas una excepción (puedes lanzar la misma capturada o crear una nueva). Se interrumpirá la ejecución normal hasta que se gestione la excepción en otra cláusula `catch` o se salga del programa.
- En el `catch` haces `System.exit(0)` para salir del programa en ese mismo momento.
- En el `catch`, asignas un valor "especial" a `anyo` para indicar que ha habido una excepción (por ejemplo -1). Luego en el resto del programa compruebas si ése es el valor que tienes (de forma que solo compruebes si es bisiesto si `anyo` es distinto de -1).
- Directamente no haces `catch` y, en caso de que haya una excepción al intentar convertir `anyoIngresado`, dejas que se propague hacia arriba.